# How to have iterator chain do for_each() and also return a count?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a long iterator chain generating data that is inserted into a fixed array with `for_each`. An MWE version [(playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0cd13c27a3ca53fbafbe9c8910d6032)):

```rust
fn f(xs: impl Iterator<Item = u8>) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
    xs.zip(buf.iter_mut()).for_each(|(v, b)| *b = v);
    // ... process buf
}
```

I'd like to count how many values were inserted. A `mut` variable that is updated in `for_each` is one possibility, but I wanted to see if `mut` can be avoided. Tried the following:

```rust
fn g(xs: impl Iterator<Item = u8>) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
    let c = xs.zip(buf.iter_mut()).inspect(|(v, b)| *b = v).count();
    // ... process buf
}
```

but this does not work because I cannot modify `b` inside of `inspect`.

Is there a way for the iterator chain to do the array assignment and return the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can simply replace `inspect` with `map`:

```
fn g(xs: impl Iterator<Item = u8>) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
    let c = xs.zip(buf.iter_mut()).map(|(v, b)| *b = v).count();
    // ... process buf
}
```

This `map()` will yield an iterator of `()`s (since that's what assignment returns), but you're only counting so it doesn't matter what the actual values are.

Answer (score 0):

> A `mut` variable that is updated in `for_each` is one possibility, but I wanted to see if `mut` can be avoided.

That would have been my first suggestion, but if you'd like to see an alternative approach you could tighten the bound on `xs` to be an `ExactSizeIterator` instead of just an `Iterator` which gives you the ability to query its `len` and then you can calculate the `count` using simple math:

```rust
use std::cmp;

fn f(xs: impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = u8>) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
    let count = cmp::min(32, xs.len());
    xs.zip(buf.iter_mut()).for_each(|(v, b)| *b = v);
    // Process buf
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0b6ea2d8cac33af48940d8cdac153c2b)